# Question About Two Approaches to Classic Coin Change Problem

Tags: algorithm

```
count[0] = 1;
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    for (auto c : coins) {
        if (x-c >= 0) {
            count[x] += count[x-c];
        }
    }
}

count[0] = 1;
    for (auto c : coins) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
            if (x-c >= 0) {
                count[x] += count[x-c];
            }
        }
    }
```

The first piece of code gives the number of possible permutations of each amount, whereas the second gives the combinations, why is this is the case?

Comment: Because the code is not the same in both cases, and is written to do two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The second code updates number of ways to compose values `count[i]` with new coin. So after k-th round of outer loop we have `count[]` list filled with combinations of `k` coins only, and the rest of coins is not used yet. If we remember combinations themselves for sorted coin list, we will see ordered ones like  `1  1  5  10` - 5 never will go before 1. That is why combinations.

The first code at m-th round of outer loop fills m-th cell `count[m]` using all possible coins. So we can get for `m=7` both  `1  1  5` and  `1  5  1` and `5 1 1`. That is why all permutations are counted here